# rails trying to add an icon to a link_to in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I'm trying to figure out how to add an icon inside an each loop. The only way I'm managed to not get an exception is with this code:

```
<%- resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider| %>
  <%= link_to t('.sign_in_with', provider: oauth_provider_human_name(provider)),
              omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider),
              class: oauth_provider_class(provider) %>
    <i class="fa fa-flag"></i>
<% end -%>
```

but the icon obviously ends up outside the link which wont work for me.

Following FontAwesome's documentation [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass) there should be a way to use `icon('flag')`, but how do I include that in the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
<%= link_to ('<i class="fa fa-flag"></i>'+t('.sign_in_with', provider: oauth_provider_human_name(provider))).html_safe, omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider),class: oauth_provider_class(provider)%>
```

or

```
<%= link_to omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider),class: oauth_provider_class(provider) do %>
 <i class="fa fa-flag"></i>
 <%= t('.sign_in_with', provider: oauth_provider_human_name(provider)) %>
<% end %>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `link_to` as a ***block***

```
<%= link_to omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider),class: oauth_provider_class(provider) do %>
  <%= t('.sign_in_with', provider: oauth_provider_human_name(provider)) %>
  <i class="fa fa-flag"></i>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have tried that but get the following error: _links.html.erb where line #24 raised:

undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/users/auth/google_oauth2":String

Comment: @just_user Updated!